# Homework Help; Reading from multiple files into Vectors/Arrays

Tags: java, vector, iteration, textinput

Okay my assignment is to read in from 2 separate files.  The first file reads in "HallOfFameMember" and should then be stored in a vector.

The second should read in and then be stored to an array of HallOfFame

The HallOfFameMember object has 10 fields.  In order firstName, lastName, deceased, month born, day born, year born, totalEarned, yearsPlayed, yearInducted, hall of fame id

The day/month/year born are all going to a separate class to create a date born.  The date born is then set within HallOfFameMember.  The Fields for a record will be separated by varying numbers of spaces and/or tabs (whitespaces).

After reading a record from this file, call the 10-arg constructor of HallOfFameMember, using the fields from the record as arguments in the constructor call.  Add this new HallOfFameMember object to tempHallOfFameMemberVec.

The HallOfFame object has 5 fields. In order hallOfFameId, city, costToVisit, numberOfVisitorsPerYear, and name.

After reading a record from this file, call the 5-arg constructor of class HallOfFame, using the arguments obtained from the line in the file.   Add this new HallOfFame object to tempHallOfFameArr.

This is all to be done from the command line.

I know that my current code will not work, I was just trying to figure out some way to do this.  Vectors are completely new to me, along with BufferedReader, and I've been trying to use the examples on javapractice.com as well as a few other sites for reference.  I know it will be something small that I am overlooking/missing and Ill have a duh moment when I figure it out.

At any rate my current question is this.

How do I read in from a file that has "any number of white spaces/tabs" as the delimiter.  And then parse that into the appropriate fields within the appropriate class?

Giving me the code isn't gonna help, if you could just point me to a website or link that I can read to have my duh moment that would be great.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Vector;

public class HW4 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FileReader inputFileA = new FileReader("");
        FileReader inputFileB = new FileReader("");


        BufferedReader inputB = new BufferedReader(inputFileB);

        Vector<HallOfFameMember> tempHallOfFameMemberVec = new Vector<HallOfFameMember>();


        try{
            BufferedReader inputA = new BufferedReader(inputFileA);
            try {
                String line = null;

                while ((line = inputA.readLine()) != null){

                }
            }

        }

        String newHallOfFameLine = inputB.toString();
        String delims = "[ \t]";
        HallOfFame[] tempHallOfFameArr = newHallOfFameLine.split(delims);

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 5) {
            tempHallOfFameArr[i/5].setHallOfFameId(Integer.parseInt(args[i]));
            tempHallOfFameArr[i/5].setCity(args[i+1]);
            tempHallOfFameArr[i/5].setCostToVisit(Integer.parseInt(args[i+2]));
            tempHallOfFameArr[i/5].setNumberOfVisitorsPerYear(Integer.parseInt(args[i+3]));
            tempHallOfFameArr[i/5].setName(args[i+4]);

        }




        }

class HallOfFameMember {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private boolean deceased;
    private int dateOfBirth;
    private double totalEarned;
    private int yearsPlayed;
    private int yearInducted;
    private int HallOfFameId;

    public HallOfFameMember() {
    }

    public HallOfFameMember(String firstName, String lastName,
            boolean deceased, int day, int month, int year, double totalEarned,
            int yearsPlayed, int yearInducted, int hallOfFameId) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.deceased = deceased;
        this.dateOfBirth = month + day + year;
        this.totalEarned = totalEarned;
        this.yearsPlayed = yearsPlayed;
        this.yearInducted = yearInducted;
        HallOfFameId = hallOfFameId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public boolean isDeceased() {
        return deceased;
    }

    public void setDeceased(boolean deceased) {
        this.deceased = deceased;
    }

    public int getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(int dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public double getTotalEarned() {
        return totalEarned;
    }

    public void setTotalEarned(double totalEarned) {
        this.totalEarned = totalEarned;
    }

    public int getYearsPlayed() {
        return yearsPlayed;
    }

    public void setYearsPlayed(int yearsPlayed) {
        this.yearsPlayed = yearsPlayed;
    }

    public int getYearInducted() {
        return yearInducted;
    }

    public void setYearInducted(int yearInducted) {
        this.yearInducted = yearInducted;
    }

    public int getHallOfFameId() {
        return HallOfFameId;
    }

    public void setHallOfFameId(int hallOfFameId) {
        HallOfFameId = hallOfFameId;
    }

    public double averageYearlySalary(double averageYearlySalary) {
        return averageYearlySalary = (totalEarned / yearsPlayed);
    }
}

class Date {

    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int year;

    public Date(int month, int day, int year) {
        super();
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

}

class HallOfFame {
    private int hallOfFameId;// ID of the hall of fame
    private String name;// Name of the hall of fame
    private String city;// the city in which the hall of fame is located
    private double costToVisit;// cost in dollars for a visitor to a hall of
                                // fame for 1 day
    private int numberOfVisitorsPerYear;
    private static final double maxCostToVisit = 37.50;

    public HallOfFame() {

    }

    public HallOfFame(int hallOfFameId, String name, String city,
            double costToVisit, int numberOfVisitorsPerYear) {
        super();
        this.hallOfFameId = hallOfFameId;
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
        this.costToVisit = costToVisit;
        this.numberOfVisitorsPerYear = numberOfVisitorsPerYear;
    }

    public int getHallOfFameId() {
        return hallOfFameId;
    }

    public void setHallOfFameId(int hallOfFameId) {
        this.hallOfFameId = hallOfFameId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public double getCostToVisit() {
        if (costToVisit <= maxCostToVisit) {
            return costToVisit;
        } else
            return maxCostToVisit;
    }

    public void setCostToVisit(double costToVisit) {
        this.costToVisit = costToVisit;
    }

    public int getNumberOfVisitorsPerYear() {
        return numberOfVisitorsPerYear;
    }

    public void setNumberOfVisitorsPerYear(int numberOfVisitorsPerYear) {
        this.numberOfVisitorsPerYear = numberOfVisitorsPerYear;
    }

    public static double getMaxcosttovisit() {
        return maxCostToVisit;
    }

    public double totalAnnualRevenue(double totalAnnualRevenue) {
        totalAnnualRevenue += costToVisit * numberOfVisitorsPerYear;
        return totalAnnualRevenue;

    }

}


class ReportWriter{

    private Vector<HallOfFameMember> hallOfFameMemberVec;
    private HallOfFame[] hallOfFameArr;

    public ReportWriter() {

    }

    public Vector<HallOfFameMember> getHallOfFameMemberVec() {
        return hallOfFameMemberVec;
    }

    public void setHallOfFameMemberVec(Vector<HallOfFameMember> hallOfFameMemberVec) {
        this.hallOfFameMemberVec = hallOfFameMemberVec;
    }

    public HallOfFame[] getHallOfFameArr() {
        return hallOfFameArr;
    }

    public void setHallOfFameArr(HallOfFame[] hallOfFameArr) {
        this.hallOfFameArr = hallOfFameArr;
    }

    public void displayReports(){

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple tips:

I don't want to do your homework for you, but I can't think of a quick tutorial to point you to that covers exactly what you're doing.

You're on the right track with .split, but your delimiter expression won't work for multiple spaces/tabs. Try this:

```
String delims = "\\s+";
```

That will break up your string on any consecutive sequence of one or more whitespace characters.

Also, you need to move the split up into your while loop, as well as the creation of each HallOfFameMember object. In each iteration of the loop you want to:

1. Split the line that you read from the file to create an array of strings representing the values for one record.
2. Create a new HallOfFameMember using the values from your string array. (tempHallOfFameArr[0] for first name, tempHallOfFameArr[1] for last name, etc.)
3. Add the new HallOfFameMember that you created to your vector

If you'd like more detail on any of these steps, I'm happy to elaborate.

Comment: I'd just like to comment that \\s+ is a very handy regex to remember for the rest of your programming career